Dealing with gid collisions when rebuilding a Linux system around an existing disk
I am currently rebuilding a Linux system, migrating to a new distribution (Ubuntu 24.04).
I have one disk which holds several terabytes of user data, which I want to keep. The disk holds a btrfs filesystem with read-only snapshots, which limits my options when it comes to adapting the disk contents (I can’t easily change the read-only snapshots).
Now the new Linux distribution, by default, comes with some groups which have IDs starting at 1000 and which have permissions on the system. These, however, are identical with group IDs I used in my old installation and which have permissions on the btrfs filesystem. Due to the read-only snapshots, I can‘t easily update group IDs on the user data.
I’ve been pointed to ID-mapped mounts, but no useful instructions on how to use them.
Can I map the filesystem in such a way that filesystem gid 1000 corresponds to, say, system gid 1024? How would I enter that in /etc/fstab so the filesystem is mounted on boot?

Ubuntu 24.04 is sufficiently recent to have full support for ID-mapped mounts, including in standard mount tools.
For mount, this is specified through the X-mount.idmap= option, followed by at least one mapping. Multiple mappings are separated by spaces.
A mapping takes the form [(u|g|b):]mount_id:local_id:range, where:

u denotes a mapping for user IDs, g denotes a mapping for group IDs, b or no prefix denotes a mapping for both user and group IDs.
mount_id is the first ID as it appears on the mounted filesystem
local_id is the ID on the local system which corresponds to mount_id
range is the number of consecutive IDs to map (the highest ones being mount_id + range - 1 and local_id + range - 1)

As soon as idmapping is used, any unmapped IDs on the mounted filesystem will translate to nobody (uid 65534) and nogroup (gid 65534), respectively.
When specifying this option with multiple options on the command line, the entire options block must be quoted so it will be treated as one argument, despite the space.
The command line for mounting a filesystem where uids are identical to the local system but gids are off by 24 (local gid 1024 corresponds to 1000 on the disk), for a maximum uid/gid of 65534, would thus be (other mount options may vary):
mount -t btrfs /dev/sdx9 /mnt/idmapped -o "rw,X-mount.idmap=u:0:0:65535 g:1000:1024:65511 g:0:0:1000"

The /etc/fstab entry looks similar, except the space character(s) in the options would need to be escaped – like on the shell, whitespace characters in /etc/fstab are treated as delimiters. According to the man pages, space characters in the mount path are escaped as \040 (octal). While not explicitly mentioned, it works for options as well. So the etc/fstab entry would be:
/dev/sdx9 /mnt/idmapped btrfs -o rw,X-mount.idmap=u:0:0:65535\040g:1000:1024:65511\040g:0:0:1000

